# Cannot install python-pip with yum

Tags: python, centos-7, pip

I am trying to install python-pip in a centos7 docker container, but I think I may be missing some package or something.

```
[root@aasdfasdfa /]# yum -y install python-pip
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
base                                                                                                                                                                          | 3.6 kB  00:00:00     
extras                                                                                                                                                                        | 3.4 kB  00:00:00     
updates                                                                                                                                                                       | 3.4 kB  00:00:00     
updates/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                                                                   | 8.4 MB  00:00:31     
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: repos.lax.quadranet.com
 * extras: mirrors.unifiedlayer.com
 * updates: mirrors.usc.edu
No package python-pip available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

What do I need to run before `yum -y install python-pip` so that it will install correctly.  Note that `easy_install` is also broken so thats not an option.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You have to enable the EPEL repo, use:

`yum --enablerepo=extras install epel-release`

This command will install the correct EPEL repository for the CentOS version you are running.

After this you will be able to install python-pip.

Comment: In my case, after installing epel-release I still have to tell yum to use the epel repo when I want to install something. Something like: yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="epel" install PACKAGE.

Answer (score 11):

I was going crazy about the same issue. The reason why yum couldn't find python-pip was that it is not called python-pip anymore.
Starting with EPEL Version 7 it is renamed to identify the python version.
On my centOS machine i can find now the following python*-pip packages.

```
[root@asdasdasdasdsa ~]# yum info python*-pip
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.rz.uni-frankfurt.de
 * epel: mirrors.mit.edu
 * extras: mirror.23media.de
 * updates: ftp.plusline.de
Available Packages
Name        : python2-pip
Arch        : noarch
Version     : 8.1.2
Release     : 5.el7
Size        : 1.7 M
Repo        : epel/x86_64
Summary     : A tool for installing and managing Python 2 packages
URL         : http://www.pip-installer.org
License     : MIT
Description : Pip is a replacement for `easy_install
            : <http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall>`_.  It uses mostly the
            : same techniques for finding packages, so packages that were made
            : easy_installable should be pip-installable as well.

Name        : python34-pip
Arch        : noarch
Version     : 8.1.2
Release     : 5.el7
Size        : 1.7 M
Repo        : epel/x86_64
Summary     : A tool for installing and managing Python3 packages
URL         : http://www.pip-installer.org
License     : MIT
Description : Pip is a replacement for `easy_install
            : <http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall>`_.  It uses mostly the
            : same techniques for finding packages, so packages that were made
            : easy_installable should be pip-installable as well.
```

Comment: `yum install python-pip` works the same on RHEL/CentOS v7, because `python2-pip` provides `python-pip` (you can check using `yum provides python-pip`). So I guess you had another issue.

Answer (score 6):

The CentOS Docker image doesn't include the EPEL repository by default, as a regular CentOS installation does. You should `yum install epel-release` first -- after that, `yum install python-pip` should work.

Answer (score 3):

For CentOS 8 you need to run these commands:

```
dnf install python2-pip # For Python 2
dnf install python3-pip # For Python 3
```

Then you can use pip3 or pip2

Comment: so it was `pip2` or `pip3` not just `pip`. I was always getting `-bash: pip: command not found`

Answer (score 1):

If you get the same error even after installing the epel repo, try:

```
sudo yum install -y --enablerepo="epel" python-pip
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow these commands step by step:

```
yum install python36
yum install python36-devel
yum install python36-setuptools
easy_install-3.6 pip
```

Once done check the python version

```
python3.6 -V
```